# Нулевые значения в столбцах данных при кластеризации на Python

Tags: python

Дано: Таблица количества кликов 30-ти пользователей для разных активностей (20 столбцов). Имеются нули, не более 8-10%. Из комментариев других известно что нули (отсутствие активности по некот. столбцам) затрудняют процедуру кластеризации или делают нвозможной. Скажите пожалуйста как нужно преобразовать данные для методов кластеризации (к-средних, иерархич. и др.) в Python? Часть данных на рисунке ниже. Min=1. Max<=600. Спасибо.

[image: Часть таблицы числа кликов пользователей]

Comment: А нули у вас значат что-то особенное, почему вы их выделили в своём вопросе?

Comment: Я уточнил вопрос. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой путь - это использовать `sklearn`, который все это умеет.
Так как вопрос очень общий, могу лишь только ссылку дать на документацию + хабр:

1. [sklearn-kmeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)
2. [Хабр-1](https://habr.com/ru/company/spbifmo/blog/534410/)